# How do I read the values of an excel files in laravel with importing it to database first?

Tags: excel, laravel

I am trying to read an excel file in laravel using Maatwebsite

But I don't want to store it in the database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required',
    );

    $request->validate($rules);

    try {
        Excel::import($request->file('file'), function ($reader) {

            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $value) {
                echo $key;
            }
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }

}
```

The echo show empty. I did $request->get("file") and it displays my filename which shows that it is passing an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a import class like this:

```
class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            // simply use dd() or dump() here and then save it to db
            User::create([
                'name' => $row[0],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file'));
```

check this for more info :
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html